# Clearing a radio button within a indexed property

Tags: page-object-gem

I am using indexed_property to handle a radio button which has values Yes and No.

```
  indexed_property(:additional_info,
               [
                   [:radio_button, :to_registered, {:name => 'rad_Registered%s'}],

               ])


case     mychoice.upcase.strip
      when "YES","Y","T","TRUE"
        additional_info[cnt].select_to_registered # To select Yes ; cnt is the counter
      when "NO","N","F","FALSE"
        additional_info[cnt].clear_to_registered # To select No
    end
```

While it selected the radio button using `select_`, I am NOT able to use the clear using `clear_`
What am I doing wrong? I am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method clear' for #<Watir::Radio:0x5f3f190d>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

With a basic HTML page, a user does not have the ability to directly clear a radio button. If the user clicks a radio button that is already selected, it does nothing (ie does not un-select it). The only way to clear the radio button is to select a different radio button of the same set.

I assume it is for this reason that Watir-Webdriver removed support for the `Radio#clear` method - see the [commit from 2010](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/commit/248bba33031a35eb4da091860c34ed302ad98ade). The removal of the method of course leads to the exception you see.

Note that the exception you are seeing will not occur when using Selenium-Webdriver. However, it does not actually appear to do anything as it just tries to click the radio button again.

**Solution - Explicit Clear**

If you really do need to clear the radio button, you can get around the normal user behaviour by executing Javascript:

```
case mychoice.upcase.strip
  when "YES","Y","T","TRUE"
    additional_info[cnt].select_to_registered
  when "NO","N","F","FALSE"
    execute_script('arguments[0].checked=false;', additional_info[cnt].to_registered_element)
end
```

**Solution - Implicit Clear**

Instead of explicitly clearing a radio button, you can implicitly clear it by selecting a different radio button in the group. From the comments, it sounds like the page has a series of Y/N radio buttons:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_Registered0" value="Y">
    <input type="radio" name="rad_Registered0" value="N">
    <input type="radio" name="rad_Registered1" value="Y">
    <input type="radio" name="rad_Registered1" value="N">   
  </body>
</html>
```

Each set of radio buttons with the same name are like a group. Only one radio button in the group can be selected at a time - ie selecting one radio button will implicitly clear the other radio button.

The page object gem provides a nice way to handle radio button groups through the `radio_button_group` accessor, which can also be used in indexed properties. For the above page, we can define the page as:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  indexed_property(:additional_info, [
    [:radio_button_group, :to_registered, {:name => 'rad_Registered%s'}]
  ])
end
```

Your case statement for selecting a radio button then simplifies to:

```
case mychoice.upcase.strip
when "YES","Y","T","TRUE"
    additional_info[cnt].select_to_registered('Y')
when "NO","N","F","FALSE"
    additional_info[cnt].select_to_registered('N')
end
```

Comment: Thank you Justin. That answers my question why I got a `NoMethodError` for `clear_` . If it is indeed removed from Watir-Webdriver, should it be removed from the Page-objects documentation as well?

Comment: A [pull request has been created](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/pull/236) to suggest removing the clear method for radio buttons.

Comment: Thank you Justin. So for now, I have added 2 radio buttons `indexed_property(:additional_info,
               [
                   [:radio_button, :to_registered_yes, {:name => 'rad_Registered%s',  :value => 'Y'}],
                   [:radio_button, :to_registered_no, {:name => 'rad_Registered%s' ,  :value => 'N'}],
               ])` and the code to select is `case     mychoice.upcase.strip
      when "YES","Y","T","TRUE"
        additional_info[cnt].select_to_registered 
      when "NO","N","F","FALSE"
        additional_info[cnt].clear_to_registered
    end` .

Comment: Is there an option to just define the radio button and select the option Yes vs No instead of having two objects?

Comment: Yes, you can look into the radio button groups. I added an example to the answer for your scenario.